# How did the following manipulation occur? (Complex Conjugates)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm currently solving questions based on modulus and complex conjugates and one particular question stumped me. The question is as follows:

Q. If a and b are two different complex numbers with |b| = 1, then the value of:

$\frac{|b - a|}{|1 - \overline{a}b|}$ = ?

Here I quickly managed the following manipulation considering that $b\overline{b} = 1$:

$= \frac{1}{|\overline{b}|}\frac{|1 - a\overline{b}|}{|1 - \overline{a}b|}$

My reference book has now expressed this as being equal to:

$= \frac{1}{|b|}\frac{|{\overline{1 - a\overline{b}}}|}{|1 - \overline{a}b|}$

$= |\frac{1 - \overline{a}b}{1 - \overline{a}b}|$

$= 1$

Could someone please guide me as to why the expression remains unchanged on taking the conjugate of the numerator and the $|\overline{b}|$ in the denominator? I tried thinking of it as making it equal to a number c (say) and then taking conjugate on both sides but then shouldn't we also take the conjugate of the remaining part of the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should see that the modulus of a complex number is always real, which means it equals its conjugate. Then, taking the modulus and conjugating commute (you can do them in any order) :
$$|b| = \overline{|b|} = |\overline{b}|$$
and :
$$|1 - a\overline{b}| = \overline{|1 - a\overline{b}|} = |\overline{1 - a\overline{b}}| = |1 - \overline{a}b|.$$
Hope it helps.